# Cast with variable assigned of some type

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

What i'm trying to do is do cast needed to add my controls to `Ext.Net.Panel`.

This is my code example:

```
   Ext.Net.Panel panel = new Ext.Net.Panel();
   Control control = (Control) null;//here can be any Ext.Net type as well as NumeticField for example Ext.Net.TextArea and so on
  switch (infoAttribute.Type)
                                {
                                        case PropertyTypeAttrib.Text:
                                            control = (Control)new Ext.Net.TextField();
                                            ((TextField)control).FieldLabel = infoAttribute.HeadLine;
                                            control.ID = propertyHelper.Name;
                                            //panel.Items.Add((TextField)control);
                                        typeToCast = typeof (TextField);
                                        break;
                                    case PropertyTypeAttrib.FileUrl:
                                        control = (Control) new Ext.Net.HyperLink();
                                        control.ID = propertyHelper.Name;
                                        ((Ext.Net.Label) control).FieldLabel = infoAttribute.HeadLine;

                                        //panel.Items.Add((Ext.Net.HyperLink) control);
                                        typeToCast = typeof (Ext.Net.HyperLink);
                                        break;
                                    case PropertyTypeAttrib.Enum:
                                        control = (Control) new MMPControls.Web.ComboBoxEnumExt();
                                        ((MMPControls.Web.ComboBoxEnumExt) control).EnumerationTypeName =
                                            propertyHelper.PropertyType.Name;
                                        control.ID = propertyHelper.Name;
                                        ((MMPControls.Web.ComboBoxEnumExt) control).FieldLabel = infoAttribute.HeadLine;
                                        //panel.Items.Add((MMPControls.Web.ComboBoxEnumExt) control);
                                        typeToCast = typeof (MMPControls.Web.ComboBoxEnumExt);
                                        break;
                                    case PropertyTypeAttrib.Date:
                                        control = new MMPControls.Web.DateSelect();
                                        control.ID = propertyHelper.Name;
                                        //panel.Items.Add(
                                            //(MMPControls.Web.DateSelect) control);
                                        //panel.Items.Add((MMPControls.Web.DateSelect)control);
                                        typeToCast = typeof (MMPControls.Web.DateSelect);
                                        break;
                                    case PropertyTypeAttrib.DateTime:
                                        control = new MMPControls.Web.DateSelect();
                                        control.ID = propertyHelper.Name;
                                        //panel.Items.Add(
                                            //(MMPControls.Web.DateSelect)control);
                                        typeToCast = typeof (MMPControls.Web.DateSelect);
                                        break;
                                    case PropertyTypeAttrib.TextInteger:
                                        control = (Control)new Ext.Net.NumberField();
                                        ((NumberField)control).AllowDecimals = false;
                                        ((NumberField)control).MinValue = 0;
                                        ((Ext.Net.NumberField)control).FieldLabel = infoAttribute.HeadLine;
                                        control.ID = propertyHelper.Name;
                                        //panel.Items.Add(
                                            //(Ext.Net.NumberField) control);
                                        typeToCast = typeof (Ext.Net.NumberField);
                                        break;
                                    case PropertyTypeAttrib.IList:
                                        //TODO: 
                                        break;
                                    case PropertyTypeAttrib.ImageUrl:
                                        control = (Control)new Ext.Net.Image();
                                        control.ID = propertyHelper.Name;
                                        ((Ext.Net.Image)control).FieldLabel = infoAttribute.HeadLine;
                                        //panel.Items.Add((Ext.Net.Image) control);
                                        typeToCast = typeof (Ext.Net.Image);
                                        break;
                                    case PropertyTypeAttrib.TextFractional:
                                        control = (Control)new Ext.Net.NumberField();
                                        ((NumberField)control).AllowDecimals = true;
                                        ((NumberField)control).DecimalPrecision = infoAttribute.Fractional;
                                        ((NumberField)control).MinValue = 0;
                                        ((Ext.Net.NumberField)control).FieldLabel = infoAttribute.HeadLine;
                                        control.ID = propertyHelper.Name;
                                       //panel.Items.Add(
                                            //(Ext.Net.NumberField) control);
                                        typeToCast = typeof (Ext.Net.NumberField);
                                        break;
                                    case PropertyTypeAttrib.TextLarge:
                                        control = (Control)new Ext.Net.TextArea();
                                        ((TextArea)control).FieldLabel = infoAttribute.HeadLine;
                                        control.ID = propertyHelper.Name;
                                        //panel.Items.Add((TextArea)control);
                                        typeToCast = typeof (TextArea);
                                        break;
   }
   panel.Items.Add((typeToCast)control);//that's what i need to do.
```

got error in line `panel.Items.....` cannot resolve this symbol typeToCast

Anyone did something similar before?

Thanks for advance:)

**Resolved :**

What I did was Cast my ready control for `Component` type.
`panel.Items.Add((Component)control);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little refactoring, you should be able to build the same result without use of much Casting. The following sample demonstrates a very simplified approach.

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Panel=Ext.Net.Panel" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Button=Ext.Net.Button" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Ext.Net" namespace="Ext.Net" tagprefix="ext" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            this.Form.Controls.Add(this.BuildForm());
        }
    }

    private Component BuildForm()
    {
        var panel = new FormPanel {
            Title = "Example",
            Width = 350,
            Height = 215,
            Padding = 5,
            DefaultAnchor = "100%",
            Buttons = { new Button { Text = "Submit" }}
        };

        panel.Items.Add(this.BuildWidget(new Widget {
            Name = "text",
            ID = "TextField1",
            Label = "My TextField"
        }));

        panel.Items.Add(this.BuildWidget(new Widget {
            Name = "date",
            ID = "DateField1",
            Label = "My DateField"
        }));

        return panel;
    }

    private Field BuildWidget(Widget widget)
    {
        Field field = null;

        switch(widget.Name)
        {
            case "text":
                field = new TextField(); 
                break;
            case "date":
                field = new DateField();
                break;
        }

        field.ID = widget.ID;
        field.FieldLabel = widget.Label;

        return field;
    }

    public class Widget
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Well the error is because the type part of a casting expression has to be the name of a type (or type parameter) - not the value of an expression.

Why do you feel you *need* to cast at all? Why not just:

```
panel.Items.Add(new Ext.Net.NumericField());
```

Why do you have the cast to `Control` at all? Does `NumericField` not already derive from `Control`? Why are you using `typeof`? Basically I can't see any need for any casts in the code you've presented. If you think there's a good reason for them, please add more context to the question.

Comment: because i making my form dynamically and i don't know what type will be there

Comment: @harry180: So the code you've presented isn't actually representative of what you'll be doing? I suggest you change it to a more suitable example. I can see that you might need to cast to `Control`, but that should be all...

Comment: @harry180: You still haven't explained why it wouldn't just work if you used `panel.Items.Add(control)` in the final line. Why do you think you *need* that cast?

Comment: because `Control` is type which i can't put into `Ext.Net.Panel`
to it i can put only controls from `Ext.Net` namespace

Comment: @harry180: Is there any "base class" which you can use in `Ext.Net.Panel`? e.g. `ExtControl`? I doubt that there's really a separate overload of `Add` for each type of control. (I really hope not, anyway.) EDIT: Assuming I've found the right documentation, I suspect you want to cast to `Ext.Net.Component`.

Comment: I want to cast to specific type not to `Ext.Net.Component`

Comment: @harry180: But *why*? It's going to call the same method, and have the same effect, surely? What difference do you think it would make?

Comment: that different when i try to put `Control` to `Ext.Net.Panel` i got error when I cast to Type which actually control is everything fine:) but i want do this after all statements ones not in every statement

Comment: @harry180: I'm afraid I couldn't understand that comment at all, but I'm suggesting that your last line should be: `panel.Items.Add((Component) control);` Or change your `control` variable to be of type `Component` instead. You can get rid of `typeToCast` completely.

Comment: Note that you can move the `control.ID` assignment and probably `control.FieldLabel` assignment outside your switch block as well, in the same way...

Comment: @harry180: Looks like you've arrived at a solution, but as mentioned by Jon-Skeet, you're forcing lots of unnecessary Casting, which may(should) not be required. I created a very simplified sample which might help with re-engineering your original approach, but I'll have to post a full code sample in a new Answer to get readable formatting.